# Magento2: How can call custom block after product title via xml in product list page?

Tags: magento2

I have tried below code but unable to call my custom block below product title or product price in list page. file-name of my module: catalog_category_view.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
               <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Wishlist"
                       name="category.product.mwishlist" as="mwishlist" after="-"
                       template="Magenest_MultipleWishlist::catalog/product/list/mwishlist.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>

        <move element="category.product.mwishlist" destination="product.info.main"  after="-" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Anyone have and idea how can show my custom block after product price/title in product list page?

Comment: can you place any image that where exactly you want it & currently where it is coming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

Add the below code to your catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
         <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Wishlist"  name="category.product.mwishlist" template="Magenest_MultipleWishlist::catalog/product/list/mwishlist.phtml" after="page.main.title">
         </block>
    </referenceContainer>
 </body>
</page>
```

Hope this will work out for you .

Comment: If that doesn't place you correctly then you can add like after="product.info.stock.sku"